# Shortcut for switching between dark mode and light mode in iterm2?

Tags: iterm2

I'm using iTerm2 (Build 3.4.4) and after a slip on the keyboard, I accidentally switched to dark mode:

[image: dark terminal]

I've tried my best to find the keyboard combination to press to revert it, but I've yet failed to find it. If I right-click on the window and then go to "edit session", I see that the "Light" color scheme is selected:

[image: preferences]

But it doesn't seem to matter which profile I choose, the session will not go back to "light" mode.

So my question is, how can I get back to the "light profile" for this session, and what's the keyboard shortcut?